# How to fetch data from multiselect dropdown and display while editing in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

fetching the data from multiselect dropdown and updating the data using codeigniter php.Unable to fetch the data from multiselect dropdown. While adding the data it is inserting successfully.But while i am trying to fetch the data to edit not able to get the multiselect dropdown list.

Controller:

```
function edit()
{
  $data['categorylist']=$this->blogs_model->categories_dropdown();
  $data['records']= $this->blogs_model->getblogsdata($this->uri->segment(3));
  $data['mainpage']='blogs';
  $data['mode']='edit';
  $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}

function editblogs()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="message error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_id','Category Name','required');        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blog_title','Blog Title');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {         
        $data['categorylist']=$this->blogs_model->categories_dropdown();
        $data['records']=$this->blogs_model->getblogsdata($this->input->post('blog_id'));
        $data['mainpage']='blogs';
        $data['mode']='edit';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);  
    }   
        else    
        {       
            $result = $this->blogs_model->update($this->input->post('blog_id'));        
            if(is_array($result))
            {       
                $data['errors']=$result;
                $data['records']=$this->blogs_model->getblogsdata($this->uri->segment('blog_id'));             
                $data['mainpage']='blogs';
                $data['mode']='edit';
                $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);  
            }                              
                else                    
                $this->flash->success('<h2>Successfully Updated the record.<h2>');                      
                redirect('blogs');                  
        }                       
}
```

Model:

```
function getblogsdata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('blogs.*,C.category_name');       
    $this->db->from('blogs');
    $this->db->join('categories AS C','C.category_id=blogs.category_id','INNER');
    $this->db->where(array('blogs.blog_id'=>$id));      
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}

function update($id)
{
    $data=array(
    'blog_title'=>$this->input->post('blog_title')      
    );
    $this->db->where(array('blog_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->update('blogs', $data);
    return true;

    $options = $this->input->post('category_id');   
    foreach($options as $opt){
    $data1=array(
    'category_id'=>$opt
    );
    $this->db->where(array('blog_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->update('blog_categories',$data1);
    }       
}
```

View:

```
<div class="rightbutton fr">
            <?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>
            <?php foreach($records as $r):?>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        $form_attributes  = array('name'=>'edit', 'id'=>'edit', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
        echo form_open('blogs/editblogs',$form_attributes);
        echo form_hidden('blog_id',$r->blog_id);
    ?>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="blogtitle"><font color ="black">Blog Title</font></label>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="blog_title" id="myArea1" rows="4" cols="173"><?php echo $r->blog_title; ?></textarea> 
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown" class="element">                    
        <label for="category_name"><font color ="black">Category Name</font></label><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span>   

        <?php
            $categorylist['']='--Select Category --';   
            $category_id="id='category_id' multiple='multiple'";    
            echo form_multiselect('category_id[]',$categorylist,$r->category_id,$category_id);  
           ?>   
           <?php echo form_error('category_id', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?><br/><br/>                     
    </div>  
    <?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

Comment: any help from any one

Comment: Hi Any one can you please help me this